# Why is my Mac slow after the OS X 10.10.3 update?

Tags: macos

I just installed OS X 10.10.3, and it is noticeably slower than 10.10.2. How can I figure out what's causing the slowness, and then how can I fix it?

Comment: Try downloading and installing the OS X 10.10.3 Combo Updater. It includes all updated system files released after the original 10.10.0 release. The combo updater can be installed to repair/replace corrupt system files and can sometimes fix weird issues like you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS!**

1. Force Quit all programs except Finder
2. Shut Down computer
3. Press and Hold Command+R and then press power
4. Click on Disk Utility and Continue
5. Click on the 2nd Hard drive ex: 'Macintosh HD'
6. Click Verify Disk let it finish and then do Verify Disk Permissions
7. After step 6 click Repair Disk Permission and let it finish
8. Shut Down Computer
9. Hold down Option+Command+P+R and press the power button for 2 seconds and release
10. Hold keys down until you hear the startup sound a 2nd time.

Hope this works!

Comment: What changes this procedure causes the system?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the limited information you provided, here are some generic steps.

1. Open the Activity Monitor (located in your Applications/Utilities Folder).

   - Sort by CPU and look who is the most active app in there.
   - Also take a look at your memory and your Disk activity.
2. Next open your Console log (also in your Applications/Utilities Folder) and look for repeating message.

Those two steps should give you some idea what is slowing it down.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple support forums:
If you kept the 10.10.2 Full installer from the Mac App Store and created a USB thumb drive, you can restart with that and install 10.10.2 on top of 10.10.3. Make sure you back up prior to doing this. Or, you can restore from your back up that you hopefully made prior to upgrading to 10.10.3.

Comment: Yeah it was so unbearable that I did this a few days ago and went through the painful process of reinstalling and restoring a backup through a Time Capsule OTA.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with everything running slow after installing 10.10.3. I read that if you open your preferences in "Photo" and clicking the "Cloud" tab, then unchecking anything that is checked within this tab, it will resolve the problem. That is what I did and so far everything is back to normal. Hope this helps.